# Error during connect to mysql db via ssh: "Packets out of order. Got: 45 Expected: 0"

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, pdo

I'm trying to connect to a mysql via ssh in a php script.
I set a tunnel whit this command:

```
ssh -t myusername@ssh.studenti.math.unipd.it -L30080:tecweb:80 -L8443:tecweb:443 -L8022:tecweb:22
```

This is the php code:

```
$host = "localhost";
$port = "8022";
$dbname = "surbani";
$charset = 'utf8';
$user = "surbani";
$password = 'iequu2iJoo6eich7';
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $host . ';port=' . $port . ';dbname=' . $dbname . ';charset=' . $charset;

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array(
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

When I run it, it display the error: "Packets out of order. Got: 45 Expected: 0." and "MySQL server has gone away". I have no access to server, but when i connect to phpmyadmin through a broswer (localhost:30080/phpmyadmin) it works.

Could anyone help me please?
Thank for all in advance.

EDIT: I tried to add a new tunnel (-L33306:tecweb:3306) and change the port in php script. Same error in client, but the server console displays: "channel 9: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused"

Comment: I think you need another tunnel. Currently your sending the client to the ssh server. -L33306:tecweb:3306

Comment: Same error on client on forwarded port 33306, but server console displays the error "channel 9: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused"

Comment: Ensure MySQL has network connections enabled (it doesn't by default,) and that you are allowed to connect from a remote IP.

Comment: If you did a second tunnel I wonder if that would work. ssh -t -p8022  user@tecweb -L33306:localhost:3306